# How do I turn on auto-formatting in Vim?

Tags: linux, docker, vim, yaml

I am following a tutorial and trying to edit a .yml file in Vim. My Vim editor is different than the instructor's. His text is auto-indenting and adding colour formats.

[This first image is the instructor's Vim and what I want mine to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qFFF.png)

[This second image is my Vim editor. You can see mine is without formatting and colours.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z6ts.png)

How can I turn on this auto-formatting? Docker has issues building without this proper formatting of the .yml file. Thanks!

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://vi.stackexchange.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those settings are more are modifiable in your [.vimrc](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/07.html) file.

In specific what you're looking for is the `set autoindent` option. Before setting that make sure to adjust your indent type (do you want tabs or spaces?) with `set expandtab` and your indent size (how many spaces?) with `set shiftwidth=4` where 4 is the count of spaces.

For the colour format you'll want to look into [syntax highlighting](http://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-editor-color-scheme-syntax). You can use that along with a [color scheme](http://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-editor-color-scheme-colorscheme) in order to customize your Vim :)

Comment: Thanks! @Egrodo

Yes, I changed the VimRC file by using vim ~/.vimrc

Then I edited my VimRC file to look like this:

set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
colo delek
syntax on

Now my Vim editor is working similar to his.

Comment: Great, that should work. Just to let you know if I answered your question you can upvote and mark my response as an answer :)